# reorder list elements - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to reorder `<li>` elements with JavaScript or pure jQuery. So if I have a silly list like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Cheese</li>
</ul>
```

How would I move the list elements around? Like put the list element with `Cheese` before the list element with `Foo` or move `Foo` to after `Bar`.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
var ul = $("ul");
var li = ul.children("li");

li.detach().sort();
ul.append(li);
```

This is a simple example where `<li>` nodes are sorted by in some default order. I'm calling detach to avoid removing any data/events associated with the li nodes.

You can pass a function to sort, and use a custom comparator to do the sorting as well.

```
li.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
   // use whatever comparison you want between DOM nodes a and b
});
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work.. can someone please demo this in action at jsfiddle?

Comment: Works fine for me. Here is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Afbrt/

Comment: Beautiful solution. just what I needed. thank you fine sir for not making think on this wonderful Friday afternoon

Comment: I don't see why `detach` is needed at all?

Comment: `.sort()` works on array of strings as-is. What about an array of HTML elements e.g. list items?

Answer (score 40):

If someone is looking to reorder elements by moving them up/down some list one step at a time...

```
//element to move
var $el = $(selector);

//move element down one step
if ($el.not(':last-child'))
    $el.next().after($el);

//move element up one step
if ($el.not(':first-child'))
    $el.prev().before($el);

//move element to top
$el.parent().prepend($el);

//move element to end
$el.parent().append($el);
```

Answer (score 11):

One of my favorite things about jQuery is how easy it is to write tiny little add-ons so quickly.

Here, we've created a small add-on which takes an array of selectors, and uses it to order the children of the target elements.

```js
// Create the add-on

$.fn.orderChildren = function(order) {
 this.each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  for(var i = order.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   el.prepend(el.children(order[i]));
  }
 });
 return this;
};


// Call the add-on

$(".user").orderChildren([
 ".phone",
 ".email",
 ".website",
 ".name",
 ".address"
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="user">
 <li class="name">Sandy</li>
 <li class="phone">(234) 567-7890</li>
 <li class="address">123 Hello World Street</li>
 <li class="email">someone@email.com</li>
 <li class="website">https://google.com</li>
</ul>
<ul class="user">
 <li class="name">Jon</li>
 <li class="phone">(574) 555-8777</li>
 <li class="address">123 Foobar Street</li>
 <li class="email">jon@email.com</li>
 <li class="website">https://apple.com</li>
</ul>
<ul class="user">
 <li class="name">Sarah</li>
 <li class="phone">(432) 555-5477</li>
 <li class="address">123 Javascript Street</li>
 <li class="email">sarah@email.com</li>
 <li class="website">https://microsoft.com</li>
</ul>
```

The function loops backwards through the array and uses `.prepend` so that any unselected elements are pushed to the end.

Comment: This was just was I was looking for - thanks for sharing @SandyGifford

Comment: Works great. Thanks. very compact solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a jQuery plugin to aid with this functionality: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Comment: nice and simple plugin

Answer (score 4):

something like this?

```
​var li = $('ul li').map(function(){
              return this;
         })​.get();
$('ul').html(li.sort());
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UcqjX/)

I was somewhat lost you may be wanting something like this...

```
$('ul#list li:first').appendTo('ul#list'); // make the first to be last...
$('ul#list li:first').after('ul#list li:eq(1)'); // make first as 2nd...
$('ul#list li:contains(Foo)').appendTo('ul#list'); // make the li that has Foo to be last...
```

more of it [here1](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) and [here2](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/)

Comment: this line doesnt seem to work `$('ul#list li:first').after('ul#list li:eq(1)');`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at jquery ui sortable

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: While very cool, I don't need the user to be able to resort, I just want to know if I can do it programmatically, either using jQuery or just javascript.

Comment: Aah I see! Didn't really get that from your question